# laravel - modify validation rule based on droplist

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-form

I have a form where there are multiple fields including country and price.

Currently I have just two countries. One has currency format with two decimal places and the other with three.

I have to validate the price input based on the country chosen? How can I achieve this. I understand taht I should use JS to detect a change in selection of the country but I am not sure how to apply the updated rule??

Here are the rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'username' => 'unique:users,username',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'birthday' => 'date',
        'factory' => 'required|exists:factories,id',
        'country' => 'required|exists:countries,id',
        'category' => 'required',
        'rm_code' => 'required',
        'cost_basis' => 'required',
        'supplier' => 'required',
        'po_number' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required|number|regex:^[1-9]\d*$',
        'purchase_date' => 'date',
        'received_date' => 'date',
        'price'=>'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,3})?$/'

    ];
}
```

I am using [`Laravel 5 Javascript Validation`](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation)  and use  `{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\StoreBlogPostRequest', '#my-form'); !!}` My problem is that I have all the fields in same form. How can I be able to update the rules?

Comment: Please include your code or this question risks being closed.

Comment: You could define the rules for the validation inside the function handling the form itself and just test which value the droplist is and then use the appropriate rules.

Comment: I have included the validation rules.. It doesnt include the rule for price that needs to be based on the value of  drop-list

Comment: @James I am using  `{!! JsValidator::formRequest('Vanguard\Http\Requests\Material\CreateMaterialRequest', '#material-form') !!}`` in the blade.php script section. which i pasted above.

Comment: You can [create your own validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: And what is the value of the drop down

Comment: @oseintow the value would be country_id currently it would be either 512 or 784

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that extends `\Illuminate\Validation\Validator`. This can be placed anywhere in your application, just namespace it appropriately.

```
use \Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class FooValidator extends Validator
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        // You have access to all Input data.
        var_dump($this->data);

        // Check the country and the decimals in the price.

        if(VALIDATION_PASSES) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register the above custom validation rule by passing the class and method to the extend method of the Validator facade. This should be placed in the `boot()` method of `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('foo', 'FooValidator@validate');
}
```

Then implement it in your validations rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'price'=>'foo'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error `LOG.error: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method [validateCurrency] does not exist.' in /home/dmsheraz/public_html/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:2997`